# compare an object whether it contains a string or an int

Tags: c#

I have two variables that are both of type `object`.
They might contain ints or strings, but always both will be the same type.
Is there a way I can compare them to see which is larger (or same).

I know I can test for equality like so:

```
if (a.Equals(b))
    ...
```

but how do I do the equivalent of:

```
if (a > b)
    ...

if (a < b)
    ...
```

`object` does not have a `compareTo` method

Test code:

```
int i1 = 7;
int i2 = 12;

int result = compareValues((object)i1, (object)i2);

string s1 = "abcd";
string s2 = "efg";

int result = compareValues((object)s1, (object)s2);

...

public int compareValues((object)a, (object)b)
{
    if (a.Equals(b))
        return 0;

    if (a < b)
        return -1;

    return 1;
}
```

***EDIT***

I have no control over the variables - they come as `object`.  The test script is purely for testing.

Comment: May be if else conditions to check string or int, then compare accordingly.

Comment: In general, this is bad design -- why are they `object`s if you know they have a specific type? This is the sort of thing generics generally solve better. One "easy" workaround is to make the variables `dynamic`, leaving the runtime to sort out how comparisons are supposed to be done, but this has a performance impact. Another possible solution, depending on your scenario, is to get or require `IComparer` implementations for your objects or treat them as `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>`, meaning you don't have to know their type.

Comment: have you thought about making overloaded methods.. one for int and other for string ? and while calling those methods pass int or string instead of object type?

Comment: Assign them both to `dynamic`. Then compare as needed. Assuming they are both `int` or both `string` it will 'just work'.

Comment: *"I have two variables that are both of type object"* - No, you have two variables that are type `int` or type `string`.  You're converting them to `object` (boxing).  Don't do that.  You *already know* their types, don't strip away that information.  Either create two overloaded methods for comparison, or create a single generic method for comparison, or just compare them where they are (after all, what does this method actually give you that you don't already have?).

Comment: I agree with bad design comments, to add to them, this seems like a good candidate for using generics.  `public  int Compare<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>`

Comment: In the rare case where you really have two `object`s where you don't have a specific type, you can also use the `Compare` method of `Comparer.Default`. As with `dynamic`, this has a performance overhead and is not as efficient as doing a typed comparison (although it has far less performance overhead than `dynamic`). This still requires both objects to be of the *same* type; heterogeneous comparisons aren't supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my proposition. You check if the value is comparable (`int` and `string` are comparable) if so, convert them to `IComparable` and use `CompareTo`

This [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HtyCV7) works

```
public static int CompareValue(object a, object b)
{
    return (a as IComparable).CompareTo(b as IComparable);      
}
```

Comment: Returning `-2` is not a good idea, since that is a legal "`a` is smaller than `b`" value for a `CompareTo` implementation, which is, at the very least, confusing even if you allow for different semantics. An exception is probably a better idea. (In which case this could also just be reduced to `return Comparer.Default.Compare(a, b)`).

Comment: you can shorten this by using the new language feature, there is no need to cast twice.`if (a is IComparable first && b is IComparable second)`

Comment: I agree with you. Because I focused on the principle question. The handle of the incorrect case, I let the OP trait it.

Comment: Anser updated. If it's not correct type, exception thrown automatically

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should check the data type first. You never know if you screwed up somewhere. (And that is exactly the problem with this design, can't you do this more type-safe?)

```
if (a is int ai && b is int bi)
{
    // now compare ai en bi
    return ai.CompareTo(bi);
}
else if (a is string astr && b is string bstr)
{
    // now compare astr en bstr
    return astr.CompareTo(bstr);
}
else
{
    // a or b is null or have different types.
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could write `a is int ai`. Is this a new feature? This is really interesting. Also would it be possible to write something similar to `if(a is int ai && b is int bi || a is string ai && b is string bi){ return ai.Compareto(bi); }`?

Comment: It is called pattern matching @Rafalon. (And the answer to the second question is no.)

Answer (score -4):

The Int32 type has a [CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx) method ... you can either just use that or cast your int to it.

You can find out if you have a string or an int by using the [GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) of object

Comment: What about the strings?